# `Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header` locks file

Tags: c#, asp.net, naudio

Using the code:

```
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(audioFileLocation))
{
    // Do something....
}
```

If given a wav file that throws the exception:

> Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header
>   Exception Details: System.FormatException: Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header

It locks the file `audioFileLocation` which prevents it from being deleted.

Is there any way to check for the existence of a valid RIFF header before using the reader?

Comment: Most likely there is a bug in `WaveFileReader` in that it doesn't close the file. Where did you get that class?

Comment: How long is the file locked? Until the process terminates or a short while?

Comment: It's locked until I restart IIS.  It's the `NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader` class

Comment: The `WaveFileReader` class has a bug here. According to the source code on codeplex, here: http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudio/Wave/WaveStreams/WaveFileReader.cs, it checks if the file is a valid RIFF file *before* setting the `ownInput` parameter, and thus doesn't close the stream if given an invalid file.

Comment: @Lasse thanks will submit a bug report

Comment: Actually, my conclusion is wrong. Setting `ownInput` to true won't make a difference because the constructor threw an exception. As such, disposal of the object does not come into play. Instead this needs need to be refactored so that `ownsInput` is passed to a common constructor.

Comment: I'm submitting a bug report now. https://naudio.codeplex.com/workitem/16448

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a stream:

```
using(var inputStream = new FileStream(audioFileLocation, FileMode.Open, 
                           FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(inputStream))
    {
        // Do something....
    }
}
```

If [THIS](https://github.com/DevangS/omnibeat/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveStreams/WaveFileReader.cs) is the current code of the `WaveFileReader` class it uses `File.OpenRead(waveFile)` in the "string overload" of the consturctor and the `Stream` returned seems not to be closed/disposed. Maybe already the follownin works:

```
using(var inputStream = File.OpenRead(audioFileLocation))
{
    using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(inputStream))
    {
        // Do something....
    }
}
```

as this should dispose the stream.

Comment: This solves the problem of the OP, the `WaveFileReader` class still has a bug though.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @LasseV.Karlsen - maybe you should report this as a bug to `NAudio`...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same code, but just before that code I was getting my FileWriter disposed, it was writing to `audioFileLocation`

```
fileWriter.Dispose; // writes to audioFileLocation
// ...
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(audioFileLocation))
{
    // Do something....
}
```

Some computers running the code were too slow to reset to initial position, resulting of searching for wave header at the end of the file. The fix was to reset the position:

```
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(audioFileLocation))
{
    reader.Position = 0;
    // Do something....
}
```